# Does openssl understand link-local IPv6 address?

Tags: openssl, ipv6, link-local

I cannot wrap my head around why this command does not work:

```
openssl s_client -connect [fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]:yyyy
```

Note: I have garbled the link local address above with `x`'s, but I have some valid link local ipv6 address.
`yyyy` is the port number.

I get the error:

```
1995535248:error:02002016:system library:connect:Invalid argument:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:108:
1995535248:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:109:
connect:errno=22
```

I also tried putting single/double quotes, but it resulted in the same error:

```
openssl s_client -connect '[fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx]:yyyy'
```

I'm using version OpenSSL 1.1.0f, which should have the support for IPv6.

Using IPv4 address, it works.

Comment: You can't use link-local addresses without specifying the link. Whether OpenSSL will understand that I don't know, but the example you gave above definitely won't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IPv6 link local addresses require a scope ID, but you don't seem to have one. Thus your address is invalid, and the error you received, `Invalid argument`, is literally the problem.

To fix it, add the correct scope ID, i.e. the interface you're connecting to. For example:

```
# openssl s_client -connect "[fe80::e1f5:ba3f:9ae5:4fe9%wlp5s0]:443"
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = --, ST = SomeState, L = SomeCity, O = SomeOrganization, OU = SomeOrganizationalUnit, CN = localhost.localdomain, emailAddress = root@localhost.localdomain
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = --, ST = SomeState, L = SomeCity, O = SomeOrganization, OU = SomeOrganizationalUnit, CN = localhost.localdomain, emailAddress = root@localhost.localdomain
verify return:1
```